# Is there a need for the tags steam-pc, steam-mac, and steam-linux?

Tags: discussion, tags

Question says it all.

Is there a need for the tags [steam-pc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steam-pc), [steam-mac](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steam-mac), and [steam-linux](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steam-linux)?

I'm using the following links as references:
[1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/105695/is-there-a-ready-to-go-steam-linux-distribution-iso)
[2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/105855/are-steam-games-sandboxed)
[3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/78919/steam-mac-game-location)

Answer (score 4):

No. Those tags don't exist, after all.

Comment: If there is an issue with someone using STeam, wouldn't it be better if we knew which OS they were using?

Comment: @Retrosaur Yes. Then they can use [tag:steam] and [tag:linux].

Comment: @Retrosaur [See here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4638/platform-tags-are-useless)